# Unity custom trigger event

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

I'm new to `Unity`

I have multiple objects(all sharing same script) in scene and the player object(own script).

I want to implement custom listener who will inform player every time when single object do some action ( lets say some int value is 10 )

Can someone give me tip for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [delegates and events](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events). Have the event fire a function that calls a function in your player script.

(From the link)

EventManager

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public delegate void ClickAction();
    public static event ClickAction OnClicked;

    
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, 5, 100, 30), "Click"))
        {
            if(OnClicked != null)
                OnClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

TeleportScript (using the event from the EventManager)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TeleportScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        EventManager.OnClicked += Teleport;
    }
    
    
    void OnDisable()
    {
        EventManager.OnClicked -= Teleport;
    }
    
    
    void Teleport()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.y = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f);
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I need to pass as parameter `gameobject who send this event`. is good practice to pass parameter in `delegate` and `Teleport` ?

Comment: Yes, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed want to use event so that any entity can broadcast info to any others:

```
public class BroadcastingEntity : MonoBehaviour
{
     public static event Action<BroadcastingEntity> RaiseLowHealth,
     protected void OnLowHealth()
     {
          if(RaiseLowHealth != null) { RaiseLowHealth(this); }
     }
     public static event Action<BroadcastingEntity> RaiseDeath,
     protected void OnDeath()
     {
          if(RaiseDeath!= null) { RaiseDeath(this); }
     }
}
```

then you have the actual entity:

```
public class Entity : BroadcastingEntity
{
    private int health = 50;
    public int Health
    {
        get{ return this.health; }
        set
        {
             this.health += value;
             if(this.health <= 0) 
             { 
                 OnDeath(this); 
                 return;
             }
             if(this.health < 10) { OnLowHealth(this); } 
        }
    }
}
```

finally, you'd have a centralized system to listen to that, let's say your player.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
         BroadcastingEntity.RaiseLowHealth += EntityLowHealth;
         BroadcastingEntity.RaiseDeath += EntityDeath;
    }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
         BroadcastingEntity.RaiseLowHealth -= EntityLowHealth;
         BroadcastingEntity.RaiseDeath -= EntityDeath;
    }
    private void EntityLowHealth(BroadcastingEntity entity){ }
    private void EntityDeath(BroadcastingEntity entity){ }
}
```

The event is static but the parameter is a reference to the entity that triggers the event. So you can print name or get some other component on it. 
You can do :

```
    private void EntityLowHealth(BroadcastingEntity entity)
    {
         print(entity.GetType());
    }
```

this will give the actual subtype of the entity, so you can perform all kind of actions